# STM32L0 Stop Mode Not Working Properly

Tags: embedded, stm32, hal

Currently, I am working on optimizing current consumption by using STOP Mode of the STM32L053C6T6 processor.
I'm facing a problem that I can not get through, and I'm very happy if you can help.
First of all, I would like to explain the algorithm in a very simplified way.
In the while loop, I print to Pc "STARTED" through the UART-Serial converter. Next, I set the RTC alarm to 10 seconds later. And the finally I sleep the MCU by using  STOP MODE. After 10 seconds, MCU wakes up properly. So far everything is normal. After MCU wake up, I call the System Clock Config function. I print "woken-up" on the PC screen through UART. I can work this way forever But I do not like the current that circuit consume.

To reduce the power consumption, I set all the pins to analog before entering sleep mode. this method worked very well on reducing current consumption. But after all the pins are analog and MCU goes sleep and wake up, the MCU can not send to string to PC. I think UART Module does not work properly...
But I/O's and systick timer are running. I can understand this by toggling the LED in a certain delay(with HAL_DELAY)
Why I can not make it work with reinit all peripherals?

Here is my main code

```
int main(void){
HAL_Init();
SystemClock_Config();

MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_ADC_Init();
MX_I2C1_Init();
MX_RTC_Init();
MX_TIM22_Init();
MX_USART1_UART_Init()
MX_USART2_UART_Init();;
Init_RTC();
HAL_Delay(500);
while(1)
{
    printf("Started\n\r");                      
    for(uint16_t count1 = 0;count1<25;count1++){
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(STATE_LED0_GPIO_Port,STATE_LED0_Pin);
        HAL_Delay(25);
    }
    SetAlarm(10);                           
    EnterStopMode();                        
    printf("Woken-Up\n\r");
    HAL_Delay(1000);    
}
}

void EnterStopMode(void){
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();                           
__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct); 
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);


/* Disable GPIOs clock */
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();

// STOP Moda girme komutu
HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
HAL_Delay(1000);
SystemClock_Config();

HAL_Delay(500);
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_USART2_UART_Init();
```

---

#### Solved

Well, I checked the Hal functions line by line. And I saw that after first peripheral initialization (uart,i2c,adc etc.), Hal functions do not allow re-init again by checking that particular peripherals instant state.
For example, In HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) function, In order to Init the low level hardware: (GPIO,CLOCK) the instant uart modules state must be UART_STATE_RESET.
In here

```
if(huart->gState == HAL_UART_STATE_RESET)
{
/* Allocate lock resource and initialize it */
huart->Lock = HAL_UNLOCKED;

/* Init the low level hardware : GPIO, CLOCK */
HAL_UART_MspInit(huart);
}
```

To overcome this problem, I reset that particular state of peripheral init. Because without not clearing those flags, uart init functions does not enter HAL_UART_MspInit(huart);

I know that is bulky solution, but it works for now.

```
void EnterStopMode(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

 /* Configure all GPIO port pins in Analog Input mode (floating input trigger OFF) */
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct); 
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

 /* Disable GPIOs clock */
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();

 HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim22);
 HAL_ADC_Stop_IT(&hadc);

 /* Enter Stop Mode */

 HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);

 /* init the SYS Clocks */
 SystemClock_Config();

 /*Init IO's */
 MX_GPIO_Init();

 /* Clear Peripheral States for MspInit *7
 huart1.gState = HAL_UART_STATE_RESET;
 huart2.gState = HAL_UART_STATE_RESET;
 hi2c1.State   = HAL_I2C_STATE_RESET;
 hadc.State    = HAL_ADC_STATE_RESET;

 MX_USART2_UART_Init();  
 MX_USART1_UART_Init();    
 MX_I2C1_Init();
 MX_RTC_Init();
 MX_TIM22_Init();
 MX_ADC_Init();
 HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc,ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);   
 }
```

Comment: What will change about this particular example? Do you think it will be so reduced ? No I don't think so.

Comment: @nee is right; using the HAL or not is entirely irrelevant when in STOP - the code is not even running.  Olaf's personal campaign against the admittedly horrible STlib HAL is another issue.

Comment: @Olaf : Configuring pins as analogue input is recommended gor at least STM32F2 and F4 for STOP mode where it disables the Schmidt trigger for each pin, reducing power consumption in STOP mode. Not sure about L0 - the app note does not mention it.

Comment: The posted code is incomplete, but shows only re-initialisation of UART2 - which UART does printf use?  Why have toy truncated the `EnterStopMode()` function where the problem most likley lies!?

Comment: @Clifford: I know that recommendation (and I also thought about the F2/4). However, this is a problematic recommendation without additional measures, It lets pins float and outputs don't drive their external counterpart. For inputs, this increases the suspectibility for EMI. For outputs it even can lead to increased current consumption. Depending on the active duration and actual current figures, the increased current for digital IO can easily be caught by writing optimised software.

Comment: @Olaf : Of course regardless of the microcontroller vendor's advice, one has to consider the needs of one's own hardware design (or that of the COTS board) in that context.

Comment: @Clifford: Another problem is: IOs are put to min power, but Systic, UART (which implies AHB&APB) are running. Saving from those leaks only makes sense if the obvious consumers have been brought to bed. After all,the ARM cores are not the best selection for extreme power consumption anyway (some PICs are way better or - preferred for it's way better C compliance - MSP430).

Comment: as clifford said, you do not reinit USART1, which one is used by printf ?

Comment: Concerning your edit. The proper way to do may be to deinit the concerned peripheral before going to sleep.

Comment: the printf uses uart2 peripheral. I am sorry that last part of functions was deleted accidentally.

Comment: @julien I also tried that deinit peripheral before MCU sleeps and then init again. But it didn't work again.